# Dokuwiki Link to login page

Tags: php, html, dokuwiki

I use the dokuwiki and the users need to login for viewing several pages. When he is not logged in, he gets the following error message page:

[image]

As you can see I already tried to add a link to the Login page. I would like to keep the initial page requested in the link, but add the `do=login` to redirect to the login page.

```
[[#?do=login|Perhaps you forgot to login?]]
```

**How can I create a link to the same page but showing the login page instead of the access denied?**

The page is the `inc/lang/en/denied.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried with this plugin "showlogin" to display the login form appended within this page.
https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:showlogin

Basically this is the code which stop showing the default denied page which contains text message and instead login form.

```
class action_plugin_showlogin extends DokuWiki_Action_Plugin {

    /**
     * Register its handlers with the dokuwiki's event controller
     */
    public function register(Doku_Event_Handler &$controller) {

      # TPL_CONTENT_DISPLAY is called before and after content of wikipage is written to output buffer
       $controller->register_hook('TPL_CONTENT_DISPLAY', 'BEFORE', $this, 'handle_tpl_content_display');

    }

    /**
     * Handle the event
     */ 
    public function handle_tpl_content_display(Doku_Event &$event, $param) {
      global $ACT;

      # If user is not logged in and access to page is denied, show login form
      if (($ACT == 'denied') && (! $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'])) {
    $event->preventDefault(); // prevent "Access denied" page from showing
    html_login(); // show login dialog instead
      }
      # .. or show regular access denied page
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The given accepted answer is the better solution for your issue, but to answer your original question:

You can use the [interwiki link](https://www.dokuwiki.org/interwiki) "this>" to link to anything from the wiki's root. So, for your example `[[this>?do=login|Perhaps you forgot to login?]]` would do the trick.

If you do that, please keep also in mind that the core's language files would be overwritten with the next update. So, best change them by [adding a copy to your conf folder](https://www.dokuwiki.org/devel%3alocalization#core_localization).